# iptables returning error of bad argument 80

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

[image]

I want to use port 80 to display the content of port 9000 so that I can test enough before letting my users test my pushes, but I'm getting a bad argument error with my command above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dport flag has two dashes, like this:

```
  --dport 80
```